# How could I make my function r metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

[image]

I proved that this is not metric because it doesn't satisfy the triangle inequality. Now to answer part b, I assume you have to make the function satisfy triangle inequality somehow. Would the answer be to decrease the path between d(x1,x3) or some other way. How would I answer to get a full a marks?

Comment: Set $r(x_1,x_3)=r(x_3,x_1)=c$ for some constant $c>0$ to be determined, and go through the axioms of a metric to see which value of $c$ is good. (I.e., for which value of $c$ do you get all that is needed -- in particular, triangle inequality?)

Comment: @ClementC. 0<=c<=4   ?

Comment: Well, you certainly want to avoid $c=0$. And near $0$ is no good either.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a triangle with sides $3 = d(x_2, x_2)$ and $1= d(x_1, x_3)$, and select the length for the other side $d(x_1, x_3)$. Other reasonable length for the other side is the answer. The side less than  $3 + 1$, and $1 +d(x_1, x_3)$ should be great than 3. The value is between 2 and 4.